# Regex to match ALL-CAPS words of a certain length

Tags: php, regex

I have a function which fixes capitalization for those naughty users that insist on making everything UPPERCASE!

I want my function to only be called when a string contains **an uppercase word of 3 or more uppercase letters**.

Can this be done with a regex?

examples:
for example: `I = false`, `DEAL = true`, `Welcome = false`

Comment: more than 3 uppercase letters *in a row*?

Comment: More than 3 uppercase letters? So if a user writes for example "AFAIK", she's naughty?

Comment: yes more than 3 in a row, for example: `I = false`, `DEAL = true`, `Welcome = false`

Comment: More than 3 in a row, so 4 or more?

Comment: Sorry, 3 or more, craply asked question, apologies!

Comment: what about a string like `MIXedCAsEsTRINg` ?

Answer (score 13):

```
if (preg_match('/\b\p{L}*\p{Lu}{3}\p{L}*\b/u', $str)) {
    // Naughty user!
}
```

will match any word that *contains* at least three uppercase letters. It doesn't matter whether the word starts with an uppercase or lowercase letter, so it would match, for example `iTUNES` or `StackOVERflow` as complete words.

If you want to restrict yourself to words that *consist* entirely of uppercase characters, three or more, then use

```
if (preg_match('/\b\p{Lu}{3,}\b/u', $str)) {
    // Naughty user!
}
```

Comment: +1 because I'm going to familiarise myself with [Unicode character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) now in PHP regex :)

Comment: Thanks for `\p{Lu}` , now I know it better

Answer (score 7):

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3,}|\b[A-Z]\b/', $str)) {
    // Naughty user!
}
```

Let's look at that...

```
[A-Z] // Character class from A-Z
{3,} // 3 or more quantifier
| // Logical or pipe
\b // Word boundary
[A-Z] // Character class from A-Z
\b // Word boundary
```

That may make it easier to understand :)

This will match if between two word boundaries all capitals and/or if there are 3 uppercase letters in a row. Please clarify if that is what you want.

#### Update

You may want to decide what triggers a whole word with capitals. For example, this sentence would be considered *naughty*.

> I like apples.

.. because of the `I`. Perhaps you want to put a quantifier there too, like `{2,}`. It depends on what the string will contain.