# How to search for all uppercase words in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I would like to search for all uppercase words in a file but I have no idea how to do it (or if it's possible). I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255104/regex-to-match-all-caps-words-php) here on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work on vim.

Comment: what do you want to do with the results? Depending on your words it could be very simple regex, like [A-Z][a-z]+

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From command mode, assuming you do not have the option `ignorecase` set:

```
/\<[A-Z]\+\>
```

or

```
/\v<[A-Z]+>
```

Finds any string of capital letters greater than length one surrounded by word boundaries.  The second form uses 'very-magic'.  `:help magic` for details

Comment: Am I doing something wrong or your expressions are not ok? I get all the words highlighted, lowercase and uppercase too... i'm using gvim

Comment: Thanks William, that was the problem

Comment: sagod's answer is superior, since it does not depend on the setting of `ignorecase`

Answer (score 26):

The shortest answer: `/\<\u\+\>`

Comment: @sica07 "\u" means uppercase letter like [A-Z].

Comment: @sica07 you can also use Vim's help: `:help \u`

Comment: `\u` doesn't match accented uppercase characters (e.g. `Ł` and `Ê`) , use `/\<[[:upper:]]\+\>` if you want to match those too

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of all the matching uppercase words (i.e. you aren't interested in jumping from one word to the other), you can use:

```
echo filter(split(join(getline(1, '$'), ' '), '\v(\s|[[:punct:]])'), 'v:val =~ "\\v<\\u+>"')
```

With:

- `getline(1, '$')` that returns a list of all the lines from the current buffer
- `join(lines, ' ')` that flattens this list of lines
- `split(all_text, separators_regex)` that build a list of word-like elements
- and finally `filter(words, uppercase-condition)` that selects only the uppercase words.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I just want to jump from one to other